# Symmetric pairing functions?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, natural-numbers, symmetric-functions

Most common [pairing functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) $\pi: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, like the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function), are not [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function) (i.e $\pi(k_1, k_2) \neq \pi(k_2, k_1)$), it seems to me. [Xie 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.10752) defines a symmetric one, but "just" on the positive integers.

Question: are there any known *symmetric* pairing functions defined on the *natural numbers*?

Comment: Can't you just take a symmetric one $s:\Bbb N_+\times\Bbb N_+\to \Bbb N_+$ and consider $\pi(n,m)=s(n+1,m+1)-1$?

Comment: Also: I'm probably missing an obvious convention, but aren't pairing functions supposed to be injective, thereby invalidating the demand that $F(x,y)=F(y,x)$ for all $x$ and $y$?